# My web server will return an html file but not a jpg file. The site is a default apache2

Tags: html, jpeg

The base directory is `/var/www-ssl/html` with a subdirectory`/Images`.
If I place an HTML file in the folder Images, `https://localhost/Images/test.html`returns the HTML page.

But `https://localhost/Images/test.jpg` returns file not found.
The `test.jpg` is a valid file.
I can open it directly from the folder.

Comment: which server are you using apache, jetty, node?

Comment: Check the file permissions - if they're readable by the web server user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is Apache. The paths and permissions must be correct since it does return an HTML page. Is there a setting that allows certain types of files?

Comment: Solved! The jpg files had a leading space. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the root folder is configured properly in the server. Since there is no information regarding the server. I am giving an example for apache

In Apache you have to go to conf and verify whether the document root is 
/var/www-ssl/html/ if not then

```
DocumentRoot: /var/www-ssl/html/

<Directory "/var/www-ssl/html/"></Directory>
```

Comment: It was a dumb mistake. The file name is case sensetive and I had the wrong case.